# SOLR ports in use

Tags: ubuntu

I am running Ubuntu 18.04LTS and have Solr 8.7 installed. All is running fine, but I did a `ps -aux` and found that in addition to port 8983, java is also listening on port 7983. Yet I find no reference to this port anywhere.  What is this port used for with Solr?

Answer (score 5):

SOLR seems to use a Jetty J2EE server, and port 7983 seems to be the default port number for Jetty's `-DSTOP.PORT` setting when used as part of SOLR.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Secure_Termination

https://linuxhint.com/apache-solr-setup-a-node/

Putting this together, it means SOLR's Jetty J2EE uses the port 7983 for shutdown requests. To generate a valid request for a controlled Jetty shutdown, you will need the value of the `-DSTOP.KEY` parameter too. If that parameter was not specified on startup, Jetty should have generated a random stop key and printed it on its standard output.

You should definitely allow access to that port only from systems used to manage SOLR, or perhaps from localhost only. If the `-DSTOP.KEY` parameter is visible in the `ps -aux` listing, you should assume that anyone who can log into the system will also be able to shut down SOLR.